# Understanding indexes and column names in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to understand how to handle indexes and series and vice versa when using apply. Here is a much simplified example of my problem.

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({'name':["alice","bob","charlene","alice","bob","charlene","alice","bob","charlene","edna" ],
                   'date':["2020-01-01","2020-01-01","2020-01-01","2020-01-01","2020-01-01","2020-01-01","2020-01-02","2020-01-01","2020-01-02","2020-01-01"],
                   'contribution': [5,5,10,20,30,1,5,5,10,100],
                   'payment-type': ["cash","transfer","cash","transfer","cash","transfer","cash","transfer","cash","transfer",]})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

def myfunction(input):
    output = input["name"].value_counts()
    output.index.set_names(['name_x'], inplace=True)
    return output

daily_count = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1D')).apply(myfunction)

print(daily_count.reset_index())
```

output:

```
        date    name_x  name
0 2020-01-01       bob     3
1 2020-01-01  charlene     2
2 2020-01-01     alice     2
3 2020-01-01      edna     1
4 2020-01-02  charlene     1
5 2020-01-02     alice     1
```

Could someone please provide me with guidance on how best to manipulate the indexes and column names to get a clean output when using apply?

- I would like the `value_counts()` to have a better name than "name". Is there a better way to handle this? Do I have to use something like `input["name"]` or is there a better way?
- `output.index.set_names(['name_x'], inplace=True)` feels a bit dirty - is there a better, cleaner way?

ta, Andrew

Answer (score 2):

I think everything can be done with `agg`

`df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1D')).agg({'name': 'value_counts'}).rename(columns={'name': 'count'}).reset_index()`

```
        date      name  count
0 2020-01-01       bob      3
1 2020-01-01     alice      2
2 2020-01-01  charlene      2
3 2020-01-01      edna      1
4 2020-01-02     alice      1
5 2020-01-02  charlene      1
```

Comment: This is a correct answer but I am really looking for a way to handle indexes and column names in apply() - I'll update my question.

Comment: I wouldn't use apply, it's slower

Answer (score 1):

`df.groupby(["date", "name"]).count()`

Comment: Please always when you post a code, add an explanation how it works, it adds value to the post and helps new users understand what has been done

Answer (score 0):

You can change your function to:

```py
def myfunction(input):
    output = input["name"].value_counts()
    output = output.rename('count').rename_axis('name')
    return output
```

where [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename.html) set the name for the Series (*i.e.* output), and [`rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename_axis.html) set the name for the internal index (*i.e.* the values from `input["name"].value_counts()`). Nonetheless, you can always change your dataframe column names with [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) after your operation.

Output:

```
        date      name  count
0 2020-01-01       bob      3
1 2020-01-01     alice      2
2 2020-01-01  charlene      2
3 2020-01-01      edna      1
4 2020-01-02     alice      1
5 2020-01-02  charlene      1
```

Another approach that also works:

```py
df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1D'), 'name']).size().rename('count').reset_index()
```